# How to fix? Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Cannot insert the value NULL into column, column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I am working in SQL Server.

I am trying to load a new table (`stagingdata`) with data from columns in another (`uploadfile`). The staging table's columns do not allow null values.

I have tried this code:

```
INSERT INTO [x].[stagingdata](DepartmentCode, CourseHours, CourseCredits, CourseDescription)
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING([Course (hr, crd)], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [Course (hr, crd)])) AS DeptCode,
        (SUBSTRING([Course (hr, crd)], CHARINDEX('(',[Course (hr, crd)]) + 1, 
         LEN(CHARINDEX(',', [Course (hr, crd)]) - CHARINDEX('(', [Course (hr, crd)]) - 1))) AS CourseHours,
        (SUBSTRING([Course (hr, crd)], CHARINDEX(',',[Course (hr, crd)]) + 1, 
         LEN(CHARINDEX(',', [Course (hr, crd)]) - CHARINDEX(')', [Course (hr, crd)]) - 1))) AS CourseCredits,
        [Description]
    FROM
        [x].[Uploadfile]
```

How can I load data into the columns without getting this error?

I have tried:

```
insert into..
    select..
    from...
    where columnname is not null
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Also I am using Azure DataStudio on MAC OS.

Comment: Please post the table definition for [x].[stagingdata]. Maybe one of the columns in there does not allow NULL. Does the SELECT from x].[Uploadfile] result in any NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
ISNULL(substring([Course (hr, crd)], 1, charindex(' ', [Course (hr, crd)])),'') as DeptCode,
ISNULL(SUBSTRING([Course (hr, crd)], CHARINDEX('(',[Course (hr, crd)]) + 1, len(CHARINDEX(',', [Course (hr, crd)]) - CHARINDEX('(', [Course (hr, crd)]) - 1))),'')  AS CourseHours,
ISNULL(SUBSTRING([Course (hr, crd)], CHARINDEX(',',[Course (hr, crd)]) + 1, len(CHARINDEX(',', [Course (hr, crd)]) - CHARINDEX(')', [Course (hr, crd)]) - 1))),'')  AS CourseCredits,
ISNULL([Description],'')
```